# Setting all values in a MySQL field to 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following Mysql 'test' table:

```
id -- number
1 -- 2
2 -- 33
3 -- 32
4 -- 162
5 -- 42
6 -- 142
7 -- 113
8 -- 12
```

What would be the query to turn all the values in field 'number' to 0?

I'm trying a kind of reset.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here:

```
UPDATE test SET number = 0;
```

Comment: Brings to mind what one of my profs used to say... "there are no stupid questions, only stupid people". He didn't get many questions asked that class...

Comment: @Gustav Larsson, the system would alert unsafe :(

Answer (score 6):

You can do a simple update statement:

```
UPDATE test
   SET number = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update `test` set `number` = '0'
```

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : What is difference between UPDATE and update ?

Comment: @Tomalak: Mysql does not make any difference with case. Why are you forcing to caps?

Comment: @Shakti: Because it looks better.

Comment: @Tomalak: It's actually depends, someone like caps but another one does not Because you have to either keep pressing shift key or on caps lock to type in capitals and they seems to me like crying

Comment: @Davood: Correct. Then again, in this case, neither is leaving out the backticks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You just want to set ALL the values to zero?

```
UPDATE test SET number = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `test`
   SET `number` = '0'
```